# Does tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy return an array or a single value?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm using a custom training loop. The loss that is returned by `tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy` is an array of I'm assuming `(1,batch_size)`. Is this what it is supposed to return or a single value?

In the latter case, any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a prediction shape of `(samples of batch, classes)` `tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy` returns the losses in the shape of `(samples of batch,)`.

So, if your labels are:

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
```

And your predictions are:

```
[[0.9  0.05 0.05]
 [0.5  0.89 0.6 ]
 [0.05 0.01 0.94]]
```

You will get a loss like:

```
[0.10536055 0.8046684  0.06187541]
```

In most case your model will use these value's **mean** for the update of your model parameters. So if you manually do the updates you can use:

```
loss = tf.keras.backend.mean(losses)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: @UmairKhawaja My pleasure! If you are satisfied, please accept it or upvote it, actually I think I gave you more specific answer to your question, though Daniel's answer is also useful on general.

Answer (score 2):

Most usual losses return the original shape minus the last axis.

So, if your original `y_pred` shape was `(samples, ..., ..., classes)`, then your resulting shape will be `(samples, ..., ...)`.

This is probably because Keras may use this tensor in further calculations, for sample weights and maybe other things.

In a custom loop, if these dimensions are useless, you can simply take a `K.mean(loss_result)` before calculating the gradients. (Where `K` is either `keras.backend` or `tensorflow.keras.backend`)

Comment: Thank you daniel. I was already applying K.mean(loss_result) but just wanted to confirm.